# Gnome Nautilus - USB automount not working

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, automount, usb-drive

Nautilus does not show my USB devices in its **Devices** pane. Nor does it mount them automatically. Looking at the syslog, I can see that kernel registers the event when I mount a device. Obviously, gconf has all the necessary settings for Nautilus set up.

I've searched Internet for some info, tried some solutions like disabling legacy floppy in BIOS -- does not work. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on 12.04. I plug in a flash drive or external USB drive, and it just won't automount. I can see from /var/log/syslog that the device is recognized, and if I run for example `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1` the device magically mounts to `/media/{DEVICENAME}`. To me, this seems like a problem with Nautilus or Gnome not being able to run gvfs-mount when the device is plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two links that might help if you haven't already tried these.

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/153678
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1478368&page=3

Hope these help. The second link solved my problem, but then my USB drives were showing up in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ppa:ricotz/testing you should also use ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 (see https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing ). It could of course be a coincidence, but I had  the same problem today and this solved it for me.